# Efficient nearby distance matrix in Python

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra, distance

I need a memory & time efficient method to compute distances between about 50000 points in 1- to 10-dimensions, in Python. The methods I tried so far were not very good; so far, I tried:

- `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` computes the full distance matrix
- `scipy.spatial.KDTree.sparse_distance_matrix` computes the sparse distance matrix up to a threshold

To my surprise, the `sparse_distance_matrix` was badly underperforming. The example I used was 5000 points chosen uniformly from the unit 5-dimensional ball, where `pdist` returned me the result in 0.113 seconds and the `sparse_distance_matrix` returned me the result in 44.966 seconds, when I made it use the threshold 0.1 for the maximum distance cutoff.

At this point, I would just stick with `pdist`, but with 50000 points, it will be using a numpy array of 2.5 x 10^9 entries, and I'm concerned if it will overload the runtime (?) memory.

Does anyone know a better method, or sees a glaring mistake in my implementations? Thanks in advance!

---

Here's what's needed to reproduce the output in Python3:

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import time
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from scipy.spatial import KDTree as kdtree

# Generate a uniform sample of size N on the unit dim-dimensional sphere (which lives in dim+1 dimensions)
def sphere(N, dim):
    # Get a random sample of points from the (dim+1)-dim. Gaussian.
    output = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=np.zeros(dim+1), cov=np.identity(dim+1), size=N)
    # Normalize output
    output = output / np.linalg.norm(output, axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
    return output

# Generate a uniform sample of size N on the unit dim-dimensional ball.
def ball(N, dim):
    # Populate the points on the unit sphere that is the boundary.
    sphere_points = sphere(N, dim-1)
    # Randomize radii of the points on the sphere using power law to get a uniform distribution on the ball.
    radii = np.power(np.random.random(N), 1/dim)
    output = radii.reshape(-1, 1) * sphere_points
    return output

N = 5000
dim = 5
r_cutoff = 0.1
# Generate a sample to test
sample = ball(N, dim)
# Construct a KD Tree for the sample
sample_kdt = kdtree(sample)

# pdist method for distance matrix
tic = time.monotonic()
pdist(sample)
toc = time.monotonic()
print(f"Time taken from pdist = {toc-tic}")

# KD Tree method for distance matrix
tic = time.monotonic()
sample_kdt.sparse_distance_matrix(sample_kdt, r_cutoff)
toc = time.monotonic()
print(f"Time taken from the KDTree method = {toc-tic}")
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
How can we "see a glaring mistake" in an implementation you failed to post?

Comment: So 1..10 dimensons, that is a vector of length 1 (1 number) up to 10?

Comment: Added the relevant code block. The downvote feels unnecessary.

Comment: @user3184950 Yes, for the d-dimensional sample of size N, the numpy array that stores the sample has size N x d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

tic = time.monotonic()

tree = BallTree(sample, leaf_size=10)       
d,i = tree.query(sample, k=1)

toc = time.monotonic()

print(f"Time taken from Sklearn BallTree = {toc-tic}")
```

This one did `Time taken from Sklearn BallTree = 0.30803330009803176` on my machine. The `pdist` did little over a second. *Note:* I am doing some heavy calculations which I have 3/4 cores on my machine.

That one takes the closest `k=1`

---

For radius 0.1

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

tic = time.monotonic()

tree = BallTree(sample, leaf_size=10)       
i = tree.query_radius(sample, r=0.1)

toc = time.monotonic()

print(f"Time taken from Sklearn BallTree Radius = {toc-tic}")
```

with speed

```
Time taken from Sklearn BallTree Radius = 0.11115029989741743
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to leave the question open for a little bit more, but this sped up my computation a lot. Also, my low "reputation" disallows me from upvoting.